# Initiating flow session failed

Tags: corda

when we try to submit a transaction, it always failed, and from the Corda log, below is the last error message we got, anyone can help what does this error mean? How should I further do the trouble shooting. Thanks.

```
[INFO ] 2018-08-24T07:49:19,739Z [Node thread-1] flow.[c833dc79-501e-4484-9c43-a6924b472542].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party O=CompanyC, L=Paris, C=FR. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=4256917187941908080). {}
[WARN ] 2018-08-24T07:50:01,777Z [Messaging DLGQRf63MNQ2zpywoVzUZ3eBVB4Yp5oaA5aYSogUwzuCCA] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.sendWithRetry - Reached the maximum number of retries (3) for message ClientMessageImpl[messageID=0, durable=true, address=internal.peers.DL2zA4g5QWv3dzx985Q9PMcvrNX4DUGv2pc7DcVjNgA8Hj,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[platform-version=3,corda-vendor=Corda Open Source,release-version=3.2-corda,platform-topic=platform.session,_AMQ_DUPL_ID=8473dd65-96e3-4a45-8076-92016a03c56c]] redelivery to internal.peers.DL2zA4g5QWv3dzx985Q9PMcvrNX4DUGv2pc7DcVjNgA8Hj {}
[WARN ] 2018-08-24T07:50:01,808Z [Messaging DLGQRf63MNQ2zpywoVzUZ3eBVB4Yp5oaA5aYSogUwzuCCA] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.sendWithRetry - Reached the maximum number of retries (3) for message ClientMessageImpl[messageID=0, durable=true, address=internal.peers.DL2zA4g5QWv3dzx985Q9PMcvrNX4DUGv2pc7DcVjNgA8Hj,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[platform-version=3,corda-vendor=Corda Open Source,release-version=3.2-corda,platform-topic=platform.session,_AMQ_DUPL_ID=66467ea0-56b9-4655-8311-f0806bf7fa97]] redelivery to internal.peers.DL2zA4g5QWv3dzx985Q9PMcvrNX4DUGv2pc7DcVjNgA8Hj {}
```

Comment: Your node is not able to create a session with CompanyC. It's trying to connect to CompanyC but is not able to connect to it. is CompanyC node down?

Comment: No, I still can submit transaction between companyC and companyD. But this error node is companyA.

Comment: if there are deployed on different  servers then check the firewall settings. if all else fails re deploy and try

Answer (score 0):

This error would occur if one node cannot reach another node, e.g. due to the node being down or incorrect firewall settings. Use a tool to see whether you can ping the receiving node's messaging port from the sending node's machine.